# How to minimize response time, maximize total system performance in an environment where the the clients send request at a vastly different rate?

Tags: algorithm, networking, distributed

In a time-sensitive environment, what is an optimal algorithm to ensure that requests from all clients are handled as quickly and fairly (if competition for computing resources exists, then the client with few pending requests will receive a high processing priority and vice versa) as possible but also ensure that no server computing resources is wasted? For example, a server handles requests from 2 clients, which client A sends out request at a rate of 1req/s and client B sends at a rate of 1000req/s, assuming the server can handle 1001req/s. The rate of requests are only averages, which means any number of requests can be sent at anytime.

EDIT: all requests are homogenous and only one thread can fulfill them

My initial though is to use a round-robin approach, where each client's requests are put into different FIFO queues and the server pull requests from each queue on a round-robin basis. That can ensure that the server is handling requests all the time and the request from client A is not overcrowded by client B.

Please comment on my approach and share any other ideas you have.

Comment: Are requests from both clients fulfilled in the same amount of time?

Comment: yes! all requests are assumed to be homogeneous.

Comment: I don't see that you need to do anything, provided the server has sufficient capacity.

Comment: @EJP sorry I should have phrased the question better to include the requirement "fairness". If client B sends 1000 requests at time t and A send 1 at time t+1, it will take 1 second before client A's request is fulfilled, which is not fair for client A.

Comment: How can it send 1000 requests at a time? And why would you service all 1000 before the one from the other client? Is your server single threaded?

Comment: @EJP It's just assumed that it can send any number of quests at any time instantly(or over a infinitesimally small amount of time). It's not for any practical application, its just a general discussion on the algorithm. And no, the professor explicitly prohibited using multiple threads and let the OS balance the load among threads. Only one thread can fulfill requests.

Comment: So 'single-threaded' needs to be clearly stated in the question. Along with the prof's definition of 'fairness'. If my 1000 requests arrive before your 1, why shouldn't they be serviced first? NB 'Maximise response time' is nonsense. It should be 'minimise'. There's not enough information here to answer the question, or to even believe that an answer is necessary.

Comment: VTC as unclear until you say what 'fair' means to you.

Comment: Here are some of the 'fairness' options you have: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_queuing pick one.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your proposed round-robin processing is not related to any pre-emptive mechanism. In that sense, the definition of 'fair' plays an important role. Let's assume that fair relates to the more request you put in, the less number of processed requests are handled if other request exist. For example, if we have 100 request waiting from client A and 50 requests waiting from client B, you process 2 request from client A after which you process 1 request from client B, etc. In other words, include the number of requests per client related to the total number of request to your round-robin scheduler.